# Python/BeautifulSoup - How can I extract text between <li> and <dl> tags

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a following html code

```
<ol>
<li>If someone is <b>able</b> to do something, they <a href="/wiki/can" title="can">can</a> do it.
<dl>
<dd><i>I'm busy today, so I won't be <b>able</b> to see you.</i></dd>
</dl>
</li>
</ol>
```

How can I extract text between `<li>` and `<dl>` tags.

I have tried this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = """<ol>
    <li>If someone is <b>able</b> to do something, they <a href="/wiki/can" title="can">can</a> do it.
    <dl>
    <dd><i>I'm busy today, so I won't be <b>able</b> to see you.</i></dd>
    </dl>
    </li>
    </ol>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s)

for line in soup.find_all('ol'):
    print line.li.get_text()
```

This will print

```
If someone is able to do something, they can do it.

I'm busy today, so I won't be able to see you.
```

I want only the first line.

```
If someone is able to do something, they can do it.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop over the [descendants](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#descendants) of the `line.li` object, collect all `NavigableString` text objects, and when you encounter the `<dl>` tag, stop:

```
from bs4 import NavigableString

for line in soup.find_all('ol'):
    result = []
    for descendant in line.li.descendants:
        if isinstance(descendant, NavigableString):
            result.append(unicode(descendant).strip())
        elif descendant.name == 'dl':
            break

    print u' '.join(result)
```

Demo:

```
>>> for line in soup.find_all('ol'):
...     result = []
...     for descendant in line.li.descendants:
...         if isinstance(descendant, NavigableString):
...             result.append(unicode(descendant).strip())
...         elif descendant.name == 'dl':
...             break
...     print u' '.join(result)
... 
If someone is able to do something, they can do it.
```

If you want to do this for *all* `<li>` tags (not just the first), you need to loop over the `<li>` tags found with `.find_all()` instead:

```
for line in soup.find_all('ol'):
    for item in line.find_all('li'):
        result = []
        for descendant in item.descendants:
            if isinstance(descendant, NavigableString):
                result.append(unicode(descendant).strip())
            elif descendant.name == 'dl':
                break

        print u' '.join(result)
```

Comment: Where the words "able" and "can" went? It must be - If someone is 'able' to do something, they 'can do' it.

Comment: @Vinod: hrm, we lost the crucial `.descendants` attribute somewhere. :-)

Comment: @Vinod: Fixed and retested; my apologies, not sure how I missed that.

Comment: If <ol> tag contains multiple <li> with <dl>'s will it work. I have tested with `<ol>
<li>Around, near.
<dl>
<dd><i>He walked <b>about</b> the place, looking everywhere.</i></dd>
</dl>
</li>
<li>(<i>numbers</i>) Close to; approximately; near; like.
<dl>
<dd><i>He was <b>about</b> thirteen years old.</i></dd>
</dl>
</li>
<li>Having to do with, concerning, regarding.
<dl>
<dd><i>I will talk <b>about</b> dogs.</i></dd>
</dl>
</li>
</ol>`     Our program prints "Around, near." only. Rest of the two <li>'s missing.

Comment: `.descendants` lists only child nodes, and in document order, and the code stops at the *first* `<dl>` child tag. The `line.li` line from your original example only handles the **first** `<li>` tag in the `<ol>` tag, but my code will work fine in a loop over `line.find_all('li')` as well.